# Spring WebFlux performance on sync rest calls

Tags: microservices, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-stream, project-reactor

**Description**

I'm trying to understand why sync rest api throughput is ~6 times worse than async rest api. And how to fix it for this scale model.

Two reactive microservices:

- `Manager`, with webflux rest endpoint
- `Worker`, with @StreamListener message endpoint, backed by Kafka

**Sync** flow:

```
1. Manager receives a http request
2. Manager sends 'todo' message to Worker and waits*
3. Worker sends 'work-complete' message back to Manager
4. Manager responds to the http request
```

*Manager's waiting is implemented with [Mono.create / MonoSink](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#producing.create).

For **Async** flow, `Manager` responds immediately to request, and starts a separate Mono chain to communicate with `Worker`.

---

**Performance**

This measurements is time between incoming http request on `Manager` and `work-complete` message received from `Worker`. Throughput is how many messages this system can process, with 50 concurrent jMeter threads. All measured on backend by dropwizard/metrics.

```
      Flow     | Min, ms |  Max  |  95%  |  Avg  | Throughput 
 --------------|---------|-------|-------|-------|------------ 
  sync         |      28 |  1171 |   101 |    71 |  420 msg/s 
  async        |    1096 | 18332 | 17876 | 12549 | 2454 msg/s 
  async +limit |       6 |  1163 |   114 |    72 |  420 msg/s
```

`async +limit` - test to see processing time, with throughput limited to sync throughput value.

---

**Questions**

1. Looks like sync api is a bottleneck. What exactly is limiting the throughput?
2. Is there a better way [than this](https://github.com/archie-swif/sync-webflux-kafka/blob/3332f526482a1bb9f006d0fcc5353a1364017acd/src/main/java/com/banana/manager/Routes.java#L27) to implement sync api in webflux?
3. Are there any webflux/netty/reactor parameters that can be tuned to increase throughput?
4. Is there a way to delegate waiting to a web server or a gateway? So that "waiting" servers can be scaled at low cost and free resources on working servers.

---

**Code**

https://github.com/archie-swif/sync-webflux-kafka

Comment: There a plenty of Netty optimizations, started from switching to the native epoll transport to BACKLOG tuning. Have you also tried to profile your microservices in order to find out how Java Reactor scales and utilizes its thread pools? Here the article which summerizes my experience: http://java.msk.ru/experience-in-webflux-netty-highload-optimization/

Comment: And a second article (in Russian) - http://java.msk.ru/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%88%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-nio-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-reactor-netty-%d0%b2-docker-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5/